# p:autoComplete shows entity Id after submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using Primefaces version 5.3 autocomplete in a web project, I have written the search method and converter for the java entities i am searching for. These all work well the selected entity from the autocomplete is set correctly in the backing bean using a p:ajax tab and initially the entity name, which i specify in the itemValue, is set in the text input.

When i then submit the form that includes this autocomplete the variable in the backing bean which i set from the autocomplete stays as it is which is intended but the text input on the autocomplete will display the entities id instead of the name as i'd specified on the itemValue. This is because it is calling the toString method in my converter but I want it still to display the name yet i need the converter..

Has anyone come across this issue that may be able to help?

I have found a thread else where that describe this behaviour but it is a couple years old now and doesn't have an answer.

This thread is:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=37918

As it may explain it better than i have...

Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE: code added

Here is my autocomplete tag, complete method returns a java List of entity type.

```
<h:form>
    <p:autoComplete id="autocomplete" value="#{bean.selectedEntity}" 
        completeMethod="#{bean.listOfPossibleEntities}" 
         itemValue="#{_e}" itemLabel="#{_e.name}" autocomplete="off" 
         minQueryLength="3"  var="_e"
         placeholder="Enter Entity Name Here"
         converter="EntityConverter" forceSelection="true">
         <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="enclosingForm"/> 
         <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{_e.name}" />
         </p:column>
    </p:autoComplete>
    <p:commandButton update="@form" >
</h:form>
```

FacesConverter looks like as below, i use a DAO call to our database find the object for each id

```
private EntityDAO entityDAO = (EntityDAO)Component.getInstance("entityDAO"); 


@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
       Integer id = Integer.valueOf(value);      
        return entityDAO.findById(id,false);
    }

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
    String result = "";
    if(object != null) {
        if(object instanceof Entity){
            result = ""+ String.valueOf(((Entity) object).getEntityId());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So yes on update of the h:form after the entity on the autocomplete is selected and the submitting with the p:commandButton the value display or the entity will change from the entity name to the entity id.

Hope this helps further thanks.

Comment: mark the answer accepted whenever it helped (most) in solving the problem. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235